# No ticks on y-axis after scaling

Tags: ticks

I try to scale the x-axis with ScalingFunctions options to make the curve look a line. But I dont see y-axis's ticks.

```
ListPlot[{Table[{(x), (x)^1.5}, {x, 100}]}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[
    MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 24/12] &@{"\\textrm{Approximation}", 
      "\\textrm{Experiment}"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {Center, Top}], ImageSize -> 1000, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"*"}, ScalingFunctions -> {#^0.66 &, #^1.5 &}, 
 FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["B,\\,\\textrm{T}", Magnification -> 24/12], 
   MaTeX["R(\\theta_{1}),\\,\\Omega", Magnification -> 24/12]}]
```

Comment: Not sure why ticks don't appear, but you can add them manually with `FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, 1000, 200], None}, {Automatic, None}}`

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug.

**A work-around:** Add the frame ticks using `Show` and the ticks functions `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks ``:

```
scalingfunctions = {#^(2/3) &, #^(3/2) &};

Show[ListPlot[Table[{x, x^(3/2)}, {x, 100}],
  Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, 
  ImageSize -> 1000, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"*"}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> scalingfunctions], 
 FrameTicks -> 
   {{Charting`ScaledTicks[scalingfunctions][0, 100^(3/2)],
     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[scalingfunctions][1, 100^(3/2)]}, 
   {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]